# Django Heroku, server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

Tags: python, django, heroku, pgbouncer

I have a Django application deployed to Heroku and Postgres, I'm trying to add pgbouncer to scale the app a bit, but I'm getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

as a lot of other questions say, the problem is the SSL in django-heroku package.
So I tried to approaches,
first:
adding to the end of setting file the following:

```py
del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']
```

the error is still being raised, so I took django-heroku settings function and modified it to disable SSL directly in there

```py
def custom_settings(config, *, db_colors=False, databases=True, test_runner=True, staticfiles=True, allowed_hosts=True,
             logging=True, secret_key=True):
    # Database configuration.
    # TODO: support other database (e.g. TEAL, AMBER, etc, automatically.)
    # Same code as the package
    # CHANGING SSL TO FALSE
                    config['DATABASES'][db_color] = dj_database_url.parse(url, conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE,
                                                                          ssl_require=False)
 
        if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
            logger.info('Adding $DATABASE_URL to default DATABASE Django setting.')

            # Configure Django for DATABASE_URL environment variable.
            config['DATABASES']['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=False)

            logger.info('Adding $DATABASE_URL to TEST default DATABASE Django setting.')
```

and calling it:

```py
django_heroku_override.custom_settings(config=locals(), staticfiles=False, logging=False)
```

but that didn't work as well, I'm still getting the original error

adding Procfile just for complicity:

```
web: bin/start-pgbouncer daphne rivendell.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer -v2
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by changing this in settings.py

```
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=0)
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

to

```
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=0, ssl_require=False)
django_heroku.settings(locals() ,databases=False)
```

This worked for me because setting `databases=false` disallowed to use heroku default database configuration and allowed to pass `ssl_require=false` which I set!